# Converting values within ORDER BY clause

Tags: sql, postgresql, type-conversion, sql-order-by

Considering the following query:

```sql
SELECT 1 AS a, '100' AS b
UNION
SELECT 1 AS a, '50' AS b
ORDER BY a, b;
```

which results in:

```sql
a    b
1  '100'
1  '50'
```

What I really want is to sort column b by number and not text.

One possible solution could be:

```sql
SELECT 1 AS a, '100' AS b, '100'::int AS c
UNION
SELECT 1 AS a, '50' AS b, '50'::int AS c
ORDER BY a, c;
```

Which results in the ordering of:

```sql
a    b     c
1  '50'   50
1  '100'  100
```

as desired.

This is quite satisfying but if I have 1 mio. result rows then I would also have 1 mio. values transferred in the result response which I do not need.

Is there a neater way of converting column values when ordering?

I am looking for a way of letting the SQL server convert the column values "within" the `ORDER BY` clause but only returning the "original" result columns.

Comment: you may want to look at this function too. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16195986/isnumeric-with-postgresql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do this with a subquery (think the union is part of the problem).

```
select a, b
from (
      SELECT 1 AS a, '100' AS b
      UNION
      SELECT 1 AS a, '50' AS b)s
order by cast(b as int)-- or b::int
```

see [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/d41d8/3102) with difference

But if it's just a sample, and b is a varchar type in your table, you can do

```
select a, b
from YourTable
order by a, cast(b as int)
```

without any subquery.

Comment: @marue if it's coming from a table, and b is a varchar type, you can perfectly do `order by b::int`

Comment: I would suggest staying with a string and avoid casting to int. As usual too late.

Comment: @Used_By_Already and how would you get the desired order, then ?

Answer (score 1):

Dealing with strings is best handled by strings, if any value in that column isnt convertible to integer it will fail.

```
SELECT
      a, b
FROM (
      SELECT 1 AS a, '100' AS b
      UNION ALL
      SELECT 1 AS a, '50' AS b
      UNION ALL
      SELECT 1 AS a, 'badvalue' AS b
     ) s
ORDER BY
      a, right(concat('000000000',b),8)
;

| A |        B |
|---|----------|
| 1 |       50 |
| 1 |      100 |
| 1 | badvalue |
```

BUT:

```
SELECT
      a, b
FROM (
      SELECT 1 AS a, '100' AS b
      UNION ALL
      SELECT 1 AS a, '50' AS b
      UNION ALL
      SELECT 1 AS a, 'badvalue' AS b
     ) s
ORDER BY
      a, b::int
;

ERROR: invalid input syntax for integer: "badvalue": SELECT
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/d41d8/3109

---

EDIT in response to leading +/- negative characters

```
SELECT
      a, b
FROM (
      SELECT 1 AS a, '-100' AS b
      UNION ALL
      SELECT 1 AS a, '-50' AS b
      UNION ALL
      SELECT 1 AS a, '100' AS b
      UNION ALL
      SELECT 1 AS a, '50' AS b
      UNION ALL
      SELECT 1 AS a, 'badvalue' AS b
     ) s
ORDER BY
      a
    , case when left(b,1) = '-' then right(concat('000000000',b),8)
           else right(concat('11111111',replace(b,'+','')),8)
      end
;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/d41d8/3112

Comment: just to mention: this would not work with strings containing + or - at the first character, but despite that it would also be a possible solution for me

Comment: see above, that can be dealt with also.

Answer (score 0):

Yes either just use numbers in the insert

```
SELECT 1 AS a, 100 AS b
UNION
SELECT 1 AS a, 50 AS b
ORDER BY a, b;
```

cast to a number before insert,

```
SELECT 1 AS a, cast('100' as integer) AS b
UNION
SELECT 1 AS a, cast('50' as integer) AS b
ORDER BY a, b;
```

or in Order By

```
SELECT 1 AS a, 100 AS b
UNION
SELECT 1 AS a, 50 AS b
ORDER BY a, cast(b as integer);
```

Comment: I want b to stay in the original data type (in my case: text)

Answer (score 0):

Cast the column b values.

#### Example:

`order by a, cast(b as numeric)`