# Check if the input is integer on postgres amazon redshift

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-redshift

I need to check if the input is integer.
using postgres on amazon redshift.

The following I tried

```
select 1,
case when ISNUMERIC(11) -- like  '[0-9][0-9]'
then 'is_num'
else
'non_num'
end as xxx
```

Comment: what is output you getting ?

Comment: ERROR: function isnumeric(integer) does not exist
  Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You may need to add explicit type casts.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16195986/isnumeric-with-postgresql this will help you

Comment: `select 1,
case when cast('11' as int) -- like  '[0-9][0-9]'
then 'is number'
else
'non_numeric'
end as data_type
` this works ..but on giving `11AX` fails :(