# I need to set up a is_numeric function in Postgres to return true or false

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to make a database-level function Postgres (version 9.4) to check that a given variable is numeric.

Been messing around but can't figure this out easily and wondering if there is some built in function for htis...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [isnumeric() with PostgreSQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16195986/isnumeric-with-postgresql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION  is_number(text) RETURNS  boolean AS $$
DECLARE x NUMERIC;
BEGIN
    x = $1::NUMERIC;
    RETURN TRUE;
EXCEPTION WHEN others THEN
    RETURN FALSE;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql IMMUTABLE;
```

After googling, I've found [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16195986/isnumeric-with-postgresql)