# Postgres Select execution order incorrect

Tags: sql, postgresql, execution

The following query does not work in Postgres 9.4.5.

```
SELECT * FROM (
   SELECT M.NAME, M.VALUE AS V
     FROM METRICS AS M, METRICATTRIBUTES AS A
    WHERE M.NAME=A.NAME AND A.ISSTRING='FALSE'
    ) AS S1
 WHERE CAST(S1.V AS NUMERIC)<0
```

I get an error like:

```
invalid input syntax for type numeric: "astringvalue"
```

Read on to see why I made query this overly complicated.

METRICS is a table of metric, value pairs. The values are stored as strings and some of the values of the VALUE field are, in fact strings. The METRICATTRIBUTES table identifies those metric names which may have string values. I populated the METRICATTRIBUTES table from an analysis of the METRICS table.

To check, I ran...

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT M.NAME, M.VALUE AS V
      FROM METRICS AS M, METRICATTRIBUTES AS A
     WHERE M.NAME=A.NAME AND A.ISSTRING='FALSE'
    ) AS S1
 WHERE S1.V LIKE 'a%'
```

This returns no values (like I would expect). The error seems to be in the execution plan. Which looks something like this (sorry, I had to fat finger this)

```
1 -> HAS JOIN 
2    HASH COND: ((M.NAME::TEXT=(A.NAME)::TEXT))
3       SEQ SCAN ON METRICS M
4       FILTER: ((VALUE)::NUMERIC<0::NUMERIC)
5   -> HASH 
6     -> Seq Scan on METRICATTRIBUTES A
7        Filter: (NOT ISSTRING)
```

I am not an expert on this (only 1 week of Postgres experience) but it looks like Postgres is trying to apply the cast (line 4) before it applies the join condition (line 2). By doing this, it will try to apply the cast to invalid string values which is precisely what I am trying to avoid!

Writing this with an explicit join did not make any difference. Writing it as a single select statement was my first attempt, never expecting this type of problem. That also did not work.

Any ideas?

Comment: The order in which conditions are applied is not guaranteed and the DBMS is free to push the outer condition into the derived table (effectively eliminating the derived table completely) for efficiency reasons. Btw: you should stop using those ancient implicit joins in the `where` clause and use an explicit `JOIN` operator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see from your plan, table `METRICS` is being scanned in full (`Seq Scan`) and filtered with your condition: `CAST(S1.V AS NUMERIC)<0`—join does not limits the scope at all.

Obviously, you have some rows, that contain non-numeric data in the `METRICS.VALUE`.
Check your table for such rows like this:

```sql
SELECT * FROM METRICS
 WHERE NOT VALUE ~ '^([0-9].,e)*$'
```

Note, that it is difficult to catch all possible combinations with regular expression, therefore check out this related question: [isnumeric() with PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16195986/isnumeric-with-postgresql)

*Name `VALUE` for the column is not good, as this word [is a reserved one](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-keywords-appendix.html).*

**Edit:** If you're absolutely sure, that joined tables will produce wanted `VALUE`-s, than you can use [CTEs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/queries-with.html), which have optimization fence feature in PostgreSQL:

```sql
WITH S1 AS (
    SELECT M.NAME, M.VALUE AS V
      FROM METRICS AS M
      JOIN METRICATTRIBUTES AS A USING (NAME)
     WHERE A.ISSTRING='FALSE'
)
SELECT *
  FROM S1
 WHERE CAST(S1.V AS NUMERIC)<0;
```

Comment: I KNOW I have text values in the METRICS table. But I also know that I have no text values for those records that match a record in the METRICATTRIBUTES table where ISSTRING=FALSE. I made the METRICATTRIBUTES table for the sole purpose of filtering out the string values from the METRICS table. The problem is that the order of execution foiled my plans.

Comment: @EHorowitz, than you can use `WITH` to control join order.