# How to select column only when it's a number? Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm using PostgreSQL and I searched a few codes but nothing is working for me:

```
select nick 
from tb_player 
where nick NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%'
```

But it returns pretty much everything with or without numbers. I need to select how much nicks are just made of numbers.

The column is character varying(50).

Any tips?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [isnumeric() with PostgreSQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16195986/isnumeric-with-postgresql)

Answer (score 1):

You can use regular expressions:

```
where nick ~ '^[0-9]+$'
```