# Isnumeric in postgreSQL

Tags: java, postgresql

I have column in my database table named 'anwers' of type **'character'**. Data may be numbers or strings that's why I used column of type 'character'. And I have to calculate the **sum** of anweres **if it is a numeric**. But I found that **ISNUMERIC** will not work for column type of **text/character** .
How can I solve this issue?

Comment: My question is, column type is character but it's not work with isnumeric.But I have to use isnumeric.

Comment: [isnumeric() with PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16206123/1995738)

Answer (score 0):

In DB2, I've done something like `UCASE(answers) = LCASE(answers)` to test if it's numeric. This could work if your column is simple letters/numbers, not including punctuation characters.