# ERROR: invalid input syntax for type numeric: ">100"

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to alter the datatype for a column in my table using Postgres. I want to convert datatype from character varying (255) to numeric (10,1). I used following queries :

```
ALTER TABLE (table_name) 
  ALTER COLUMN (column_name) TYPE numeric(10,1) 
  USING (column_name::numeric(10,1));

ALTER TABLE (table_name) 
  ALTER COLUMN (column_name) TYPE numeric(10,1) 
  USING (trim(column_name)::numeric(10,1));
```

but no luck with both the queries and I'm getting below error:

> ```
> ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type numeric: ">100"
> ********** Error **********
>
> ERROR: invalid input syntax for type numeric: ">100" SQL state: 22P02
> ```

How to overcome this error?

Comment: tag the correct database!

Comment: Well apparently you have a value `>100` somewhere in that table - that value can't be converted to a number. You need to cleanup those invalid values first

Comment: your data contains non-numeric values, such as the sign ">". Have a look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16195986/isnumeric-with-postgresql) to identify the non-numeric values.

Comment: @JGH , a_horse_with_no_name :Your suggestions helped me to sort out the issue.Thanks alot.