# Postgres Query: finding values that are not numbers

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have been importing data from a Pandas Dataframe to a postgres DB using my own custom import script. Unfortunately, my data is not tidy which caused every single one of my columns to be parsed as a text. Is there any way where I could get the entries where a certain column value is NOT a number? My plan is to delete those records and convert the column to a numeric type

Thanks!

Comment: You can create a function `is_numeric` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16195986/isnumeric-with-postgresql

Answer (score 9, accepted):

get the records which have no digits, then you would have to use the following regex:

```
DELETE FROM myrecords WHERE record ~ '^[^0-9]+$';
```

Here, the `^` character outside of square brackets means the beginning of the field, the `$` character means the end of the field, and we require that all characters in between are non-digits. + indicates that there should be at least one such characters. If we would also allow empty strings, then the regex would look like `^[^0-9]*$`.

If you want the records which would include digits and lower-case letter, then I would expect a regex like:

```
DELETE FROM myrecords WHERE record ~ '[0-9a-z]';
```

Comment: the first regex should be `'^[0-9]+$` or you could shorten it to `'^\d+$'`

Comment: @HaleemurAli yes that's work as well `\d is a metacharacter that matches any digit, which is identical to [0-9]` @Macterror you are welcome, glad it helps

Comment: A single non-numeric character suffices to determine that a string is not a number.  Therefore it would seem more appropriate to use `[^0-9]+` (or `[^\d]+`) — that is, check if at least one character is not a number.

Comment: @HaleemurAli NO !  With your regex the query would delete all (and only) actual numbers…