# How to update new empty column with data that depends on mathematical operation of different data types?

Tags: amazon-redshift

[beginner]

I have a table that looks like this:

```
colA    colB
1       <null>
2       <null>
3       <null>
```

`colB` is the new empty column I added to the table. `colA` is varchar and `colB` is double precision data type (float).

I want to update `colB` with a `colA` multiplied by 2.

New table should look like this:

```
colA    colB
1       2
2       4
3       6
```

When I go to update `colB` like so:

```
update tablename set colB = colA * 2
```

I get error:

```
Invalid operation: Invalid input syntax for type numeric
```

Ive tried to work around this with solutions like this:

```
update tablename set colB = COALESCE(colA::numeric::text,'') * 2
```

but get the same error.

In a select statement on the same table, this works on `colA` which is varchar:

```
select colA * 2 from tablename
```

How can I update a column with mathematical operations with different datatype reference columns? I cant update datatype for `colA`.

Comment: Can you provide DDL `CREATE TABLE` for your tablename?

Comment: I would change title of question to: "How to **update** new empty column with data that depends on mathematical operation of different data types?". Or something similar but not **insert**

Comment: @AlexYu that helps will update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose that Laurenz Albe is correct and there are non-numeric values in `col_a`

So UPDATE must be guarded:

```sql
UPDATE T
SET col_b = 
  CASE
     WHEN col_a ~'^([0-9]+\.?[0-9]*|\.[0-9]+)$' THEN col_a::numeric *2
  END ;
-- or this way
UPDATE T
SET col_b = col_a::numeric *2
WHERE
      col_a ~'^([0-9]+\.?[0-9]*|\.[0-9]+)$' ;
```

Look at fiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4wFynf9WiEuiE499XMcsCT/1

Recipes for "isnumeric" you can get here: [isnumeric() with PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16195986/isnumeric-with-postgresql)

Comment: thank you so much. I think i found the issue. colA has a empty strings, how do I get around this in the update command? Does your update statement take care of empty strings?

Comment: @RustyShackleford Look on db-fiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4wFynf9WiEuiE499XMcsCT/4. I added inserts of  NULL and empty strings

Comment: amazing this workeD!

Answer (score 1):

There is a value in the string column that is not a valid number. You will have to fix the data or exclude certain rows with a `WHERE` condition.

If you say that running the query from your client works, that leads me to suspect that your client doesn't actually execute the whole query, but slaps a `LIMIT` on it (some client tools do that).

The following query will have to process all rows and should fail:

```
SELECT colA * 2 AS double
FROM tablename
ORDER BY double;
```

Comment: Maybe  `SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE NOT col_a ~~'^([0-9]+\.?[0-9]*|\.[0-9]+)$' ` to check existence of non-numeric values ?

Comment: @AlexYu Numbers can be negative, and they can be in scientific notation.

Comment: Ah. Yes. For that I would use something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16206123/1168212

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I think found the issue with AlexYu line. There are empty strings in colA, but I am not sure how to exclude them in the update command?

Comment: I accepted @AlexYu answer, but thank you for your help in figuring out the problem.

Comment: @RustyShackleford My answer is the same as Laurenz Albe. It's just easier to understand for novices in SQL

Answer (score 0):

```sql
update tablename set colB = colA::numeric * 2
```

Comment: I get error: `Invalid operation: Invalid input syntax for type numeric`

Comment: Sorry:
```sql
update tablename set colB = colA::integer * 2
```

Comment: You must have a value in colA that is not a number.

Comment: @Jeremy I ran this `select * from table where colA like '%[^a-zA-Z]%'` but no results back.

Comment: @СергейЗайков the integer change also didnt work.

Comment: @Jeremy i did find some rows where `colA` is null, not sure if that makes a difference

Comment: also tried adding `where colA is not null`, but all didnt work. Same error.

Comment: null wouldn't matter, but an empty string would give you an error

Comment: @Jeremy I think i found the issue but not sure how to fix. I found some rows in colA with empty strings. How do I get around this in the update?